# numpy.polynomial.polynomial.Polynomial.fit() function's result

Tags: python, numpy

I was confused while using numpy's polynomial method.

I tried these 3 methods, but only `numpy.polynomial.polynomial.Polynomial.fit()` returns different results.

```py
x = [0.0, 0.44721, 0.94868, 1.3784, 2.21359]
y = [100.0, 99.77908, 97.99978, 95.56167, 88.42727]

coef00, coef11 = np.polynomial.polynomial.Polynomial.fit(x, y, 1)
coef_0, coef_1 = np.polynomial.polynomial.polyfit(x, y, 1)
coef1, coef0 = np.polyfit(x, y, 1)

print(coef00, coef11)
print(coef_0, coef_1)
print(coef0, coef1)

>>
95.77300574959435 -5.883175469265392
101.65618121885973 -5.315506005416914
101.65618121885977 -5.315506005416928
```

I think there is something different in that function, but I don't know what it is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason is that the optional argument for `fit` `domain` differs in default value with respect to its predecessor `polyfit`.

From the [documentation](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.polynomial.polynomial.Polynomial.fit.html#numpy.polynomial.polynomial.Polynomial.fit):

> domain{None, [beg, end], []}, optional
>
> Domain to use for the returned series. If None, then a minimal domain that covers the points x is chosen. If [] the class domain is
> used. The default value was the class domain in NumPy 1.4 and None in
> later versions. The [] option was added in numpy 1.5.0.

Doing

```
coef00, coef11 = np.polynomial.Polynomial.fit(x, y, 1, domain=[])
```

gives

```
101.65618121885974 -5.315506005416907
```

as with the others (modulo round-off error), but you should instead leave this unspecified unless you know what you're doing in terms of setting up the domain of the fit.

Read more in the corresponding section of https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/routines.polynomials.html

Comment: Thanks to your reply.  
I have a question about different between of domain and window.  
If I know critical difference of that, it will be very helpful to understand about that function.  
Can you give me answer of that?

Comment: what's the question again?

Comment: I want to know specific mean of domain and window in that function.

Comment: The documentation states that the class contains attributes `window` and `domain`, which you can use to obtain what you need. For instance, if you store a `Polynomial` object as `p = Polynomial.fit(x, y, deg)`, then `p.domain` will give you the domain. Same with `window`.